# How to have a variable in a mail line

Tags: php

okay, here is the code

```
while (!feof($text)) {
    $name = fgets($text);
    $number = fgets($text);
    $carrier = fgets($text);
    $date = fgets($text);
    $line = fgets($text);


    $content = $_POST['message']; 

    $message .= $content; 
    $message .= "\n";
    $number = $number;


    mail("$number@vtext.com", "Event Alert", $message, "SGA"); 
    Header("Location: mailconf.php");
}
```

I am trying to get a message sent to a phone, I have 'message' coming in from a text area, and then I assign it to "$content" then I put "$content" into "$message" and then as you can see, in my mail line, I want the address to be the variable "number"@vtext.com I have the while loop because there are many people in these files I wish to send a message to...
When I change the "$number@vtext.com" to my email address, it sends everything fine, I just cannot seem to get it to send to a phone number, please help!
thanks!

Comment: Are you testing with valid Verizon phone numbers? @vtext.com is a Verizon only domain.

Comment: yep, as a representative sample, I have only one number registered, and it is my phone, which is verizon...

Comment: Hmmm. Can you send an email using your normal email program to the address with success? it uses all 10 digits, i.e., `4441114444@vtext.com`

Comment: I missed the real bug, and I have updated my answer. It should get it working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `fgets` includes the newline character as part of the return. So you are effectively sending an email to:

> 1234567890
>   @vtext.com

Which of course is invalid. Change your line that reads `$number = $number` to:

```
$number = trim($number);
```

And the rest of your code should function as expected, with the email being received on your phone.

**Part of my original answer**

I would highly recommend using a (probably paid) service to send SMS messages to phones if you need anything remotely reliable. A quick search yielded a few results:

1. [PHP/SMS Tutorial](http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/sms/)
2. [A list of 5 ways to Text for free](http://gigaom.com/2007/03/12/free-sms/) <-- This link is dated, but might still be helpful

Comment: I had looked into that, I was just trying to find a way to do it without paying. It should work in theory, I changed the "to" line to (myphone)@vtext.com and it sent the message including $number in the message fine... really confused...

Comment: Sorry Ryan, I missed the bug which was that `fgets` is bringing the newline character as part of your string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the number variable and the "@vtext.com" literal string together:

```
mail($number . "@vtext.com", "Event Alert", $message, "SGA");
```

Comment: This is not his problem. `@` is an invalid character for a PHP variable, and as such it has no trouble knowing that the variable is called `$number` not `$number@...`